# Sorting Parent-Children relations

Tags: java, sorting, tree

I have some problems figuring out a simple compareTo-method for my class **Page**:

- Page has a reference to a parent page via getParent() - nullable
- Page has a variable `order` which only determines the order in the same hierarchy level

I like to sort in the following way:

1. ParentA
2. SubParentOfA1
3. SubParentOfA2
4. ParentB
5. ParentC
6. SubParentOfC1
7. SubParentOfC2

How does my compareTo need to look to solve this problem? I tried the following, which currently only sorts the same level correctly.

My approach:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(@NonNull Object o) {
    int compare = 0;
    if (o instanceof Page) {
        Page other = (Page) o;
        if (other.parent != null) {
            compare = this.compareTo(other.parent);
        } else if (parent != null) {
            compare = this.parent.compareTo(other);
        }
        if (compare == 0) {
            compare = Integers.compareTo(this.order, other.order);
        }
    }
    return compare;
}
```

Edit: My Page-Class:

```
class Page{
    int order;
    Page parent;
}
```

Comment: You never compare `this.parent` against `other.parent`. You may add level property (stored as attribute or computed on the fly) to ease comparison.

Comment: Don't I do it as soon as one of them doesnt have a parent? I recursively call compareTo until I am at the top level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of making complex computation, you can simply rely on `order` chain. I have used a `String` to store the chain for each "node":

```
class Page implements Comparable<Page> {
    String name;
    int order;
    Page parent;
    String key;

    Page() {
        name = "root";
        order  = 0;
        parent = null;
        key    = "";
    }

    Page(String name, int order, Page parent) {
        this.name   = name;
        this.order  = order;
        this.parent = parent;
        key = parent.key + (char)order;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Page o) {
        return key.compareTo(o.key);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Page root = new Page();

    Page b    = new Page("b"  , 2, root);
    Page b1   = new Page("b.1", 1, b);
    Page b3   = new Page("b.3", 3, b);
    Page b2   = new Page("b.2", 2, b);

    Page a    = new Page("a"  , 1, root);
    Page a2   = new Page("a.2", 2, a);
    Page a1   = new Page("a.1", 1, a);

    List<Page> pages = Arrays.asList(root, a, a1, a2, b, b1, b2, b3);
    System.out.println(pages);

    Collections.shuffle(pages);
    System.out.println(pages);

    Collections.sort(pages);
    System.out.println(pages);
}
```

The trick here is to use a `String` as sortable `short` array. The array is compound of `order` which forms the path from root to the node. `root` has a key/id of `[]` and `a` a child from `root` with `order` 1 as a key/id of `[1]`.

Here the key/id matrix:

```
┌──────┬────────┬───────┬────────────┬─────┐
│ Page │ Parent │ Order │ Parent Key │ Key │
├──────┼────────┼───────┼────────────┼─────┤
│ root │ -      │ -     │ -          │     │
│ a    │ root   │ 1     │            │ 1   │
│ a.1  │ a      │ 1     │ 1          │ 1 1 │
│ a.2  │ a      │ 2     │ 1          │ 1 2 │
│ b    │ root   │ 2     │            │ 2   │
│ b.1  │ b      │ 1     │ 2          │ 2 1 │
│ b.2  │ b      │ 2     │ 2          │ 2 2 │
│ b.3  │ b      │ 3     │ 2          │ 2 3 │
└──────┴────────┴───────┴────────────┴─────┘
```

Here is a an example from another tree (key in parenthesis)

```
root      (     )
├ z       (1    )
│ ├ a     (1 1  )
│ │ └ y   (1 1 1)
│ └ b     (1 2  )
│   └ x   (1 2 1)
└ c       (2    )
  ├ w     (2 1  )
  └ d     (2 2  )
```

Comment: Doesnt this rely on how my parent pages are named? Having a sorted alphabetical list was just an example. It could happen that a page called 'c' has children named 'a' or vice versa

Comment: It doesn't rely on alphabetic order. See my detail edit. You can try the example yourself to check code behaviour ...

Answer (score 3):

You may have a method to detect the depth of a page

The solution is this:

```
public class Page {
    private int order;
    private Page parent;

    public Page() {
    }

    public Page(int order, Page parent) {
        this.order = order;
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public int getOrder() {
        return order;
    }

    public void setOrder(int order) {
        this.order = order;
    }

    public Page getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(Page parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }


    public int compareTo(Object o){
        int compare = 0;
        if (o instanceof Page) {
            Page other = (Page) o;
            if(this.depth() == other.depth()){
                if(Objects.equals(this.getParent(), other.getParent())){
                    return Integer.compare( other.getOrder(),this.getOrder());
                }
                else{
                    return this.getParent().compareTo(other.getParent());
                }
            }
            else{
                return Integer.compare(other.depth() , this.depth());
            }
        }
        return compare;
    }

    public int depth(){
        if(this.parent == null)return 0;
        else return 1+this.parent.depth();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Page a = new Page(1, null);
        Page a_1 = new Page(1, a);
        Page a_2 = new Page(2, a);
        Page a_1_1 = new Page(1, a_1);
        Page a_1_2 = new Page(2, a_1);
        Page a_2_1 = new Page(1, a_2);
        Page a_2_2 = new Page(2, a_2);

        System.out.println(a_1.compareTo(a_1_1));
        //1 because a_1 has higher depth
        System.out.println(a_1.compareTo(a_2));
        //1 because a_1 has smaller order
        System.out.println(a_1_2.compareTo(a_1_1));
        //-1 because a_1_2 has higher order
        System.out.println(a_2_1.compareTo(a_1_1));
        //-1 because a_2_1 parent is a_2 and a_1_1 parent is a_1
    }
}
```

Comment: I somehow tried to solve it within compareTo without even thinking about having helper methods :/ cheers!